# Efficient short life FTP server on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, ftp

I have a website for my business that integrates with other services in my industry. Most of those services send files strictly via FTP to their partners. When I receive a file via FTP, I generate an API request to the server with the website (in this case, the same machine), then I delete the file on the FTP server.

Is there an efficient way that using AWS that I can receive files via FTP, then generate a request?

I'm interested in using some sort of serverless solution like AWS's Lambda, but I'm not sure if it would work or how to go about it.

Note: The FTP server will have multiple users that will generate slightly different requests to my website server.

Comment: You can't run a FTP **server** on a **serverless** service like AWS Lambda. How do you define "short life"? Is it 5 minutes? 5 hours?

Comment: By short life I just want the server/service to exists for the duration of receiving the upload and generating the request. It has no other function.

Comment: You didn't answer my question though. How long is that generally going to be, 5 minutes or 5 hours or what?

Comment: less than 5 minutes

Comment: You won't be able to use Lambda for that kind of setup.  Lambda functions run in isolated containers on AWS-managed servers.  You have no control to open ports for outside connections to be made into the container, and that would just be the first of the hurdles to overcome.

Comment: Ok. Putting Lambda service aside, is my only option to go with an EC2 instance?

Comment: @DavidMilanese Did you ever sort this out?  I can imagine you can do it for active uploads, but not passive uploads.  This also assumes the FTP clients don't strictly require you to open connections from port 20.

Comment: @Jayden, I ended deploying a docker service based on the _pure-ftpd_ image. Then having my serverless functions listen for changes in specific directories on the container to file when a new file arrives. Unfortunately, it is a requirement that I operate ftp in passive mode.

Answer (score 0):

Serverless is not applicable to your situation because you specifically want to run the FTP protocol.

Without the requirement to use FTP, there would be many low-cost options, such as uploading directly to Amazon S3 or making a call to AWS Lambda via the API Gateway.

Since you wish to run FTP, you will need a server. You could probably do it from an Amazon EC2 `t2.nano` instance that is extremely low-cost. Just have a little script that monitors the upload directory, the takes action when it sees a file.