# Can a FTP container spin up when a request is received?

Tags: ftp, docker, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to have an FTP server running on a container (such as the docker-pure-ftpd image) and only have it running when a request has been received?

I would like to use AWS if possible.

Comment: Not as far as I know. Related to this question http://superuser.com/questions/1178243/efficient-short-life-ftp-server-on-aws

Comment: You would need a "watcher" application that sees the incoming request and spins up the required service.

Comment: What are you thinking for this "watcher" application?